# updating from 2.5.5 to 2.10.1, ERROR 1048 Column ‘field_id_14’ cannot be null

Tags: error, ee2-upgrades, codeigniter, update

I’m trying to update from Expression Engine 2.5.5 to 2.10.1 and I get this error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048
>
> Column ‘field_id_14’ cannot be null
>
> UPDATE `exp_channel_data` SET `field_id_14` = NULL
>
> Filename: D:\EE_directory\system\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 382

Answer (score 1):

Have you identified which field is id 14?

You can by looking at table `exp_field-types` or by looking at your field-groups inside the CP. Once you figure out the field in question, that may give you a clue. If unused, you can try getting rid of it.

Or you can change the **NULLs to ""** by running the following Query (backup your table before doing this, just in case):

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_14 = "" WHERE field_id_14 = NULL.
```

Comment: exp_fieldtypes only goes up to 10, so I don't think I know what I'm looking for.  I looked at exp_channel_data -> field_id_14 values in the db and none are set to NULL. I ran the command anyway and 0 rows were affected. thx

Comment: Actually, you should take a look in exp_channel_fields to identify which one has field_id 14. If you don't need it, I recommend removing it. I'm not sure what happens if you delete its record from that table, so I'd delete it from your EE Control Panel (Admin > Channel Admin > Channel Fields).

Comment: In the table exp_channel_fields, looking in field_id, the entry with an ID of 14 shows field_name is 'information_category'. Numbers shown at Admin > Channel Admin > Channel Fields page only goes up to 10 and I don't see how the Channel Fields info presented on this Admin page relates to the exp_channel_fields table. I may not know what I'm looking for.